# Uncaught ReferenceError: findWeather is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a simple web-app for my studies that shows the current weather per location and current weather on the location you type in.
I have in my HTML file:

```
<div id="data">
</div>
<input type="text" value="Which city are you in?">
<input type="button" value ="Submit" onclick="findWeather()">
```

and for the JavaScript file:

```
function findWeather() {
    $.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Eindhoven&appid=*My_APP_ID*",
            function () {
                document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = data.list.main.temp;
            })
}
```

Of course I have filled in the right App ID, I'm just not sure whether to share it here or not.

The JavaScript script won't run and I have no clue why.

EDIT: I seem to getUncaught ReferenceError: findWeather is not defined
error, while I did declare findWeather..?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? What errors do you get in the console? You probably want an argument variable in your function like `function(data)`.

Comment: Define "won't run". Does it make the request?

Comment: I cannot see if it makes the request, as I cant prompt anything, I honestly have no clue where the bug is :\

Comment: And no, not using jQuery, and Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list is the error I get, while my brackets line up fine it seems,      EDIT: It seems i get Uncaught ReferenceError: findWeather is not defined too, even though i defined findWeather right?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `data`.

Presumably it is supposed to be the first argument of the function you pass as the second argument to `$.get`.

Answer (score 0):

After passing the URL, as a second argument of the .get() function you are passing a callback anonymous function. In this function you must declare the parameter in which the data should be stored. For example:

```
function findWeather(){
    $.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Eindhoven&appid=*My_APP_ID*", 
           function(data) {
               document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = data.list.main.temp;
    })
}
```